# SQL Server row values as column names Pivot Table?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, pivot

I have the following view in SQL Server 2008.

```
DEPT | EMP_ID | EMP_NAME | P_DATE  | HOURS_WORKED
```

I want the view to be this way:

```
DEPT | EMP_ID | EMP_NAME | 2012-09-28 | 2012-09-29 | 2012-09-30 | 2012-10-01 ...
```

where the above date column header is P_DATE below which is "Hours_Worked" values of that employee on that particular date.

Like

```
2012-09-28

09:00:00

10:00:00
```

I am not sure whether I could achieve it using Pivot.

Please go to this link for clear understanding : [SQL Server View Snapshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hkz3s.jpg)

Comment: Did you get a chance to look at any of the questions displayed under "Related" section on RHS of this page, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1677645/using-pivot-in-sql-server-2008?rq=1?

Comment: Please post the code you have so far, and tell us where you are tuck

Comment: Was busy with some other stuff.  It was all that I required but also looking for SQL Server 2000. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can perform this with the `PIVOT` function.  If you know the values that you want to turn into columns than you can hard code then using a static pivot:

```
select *
from 
(
  select dept, emp_id, emp_name, p_date, hours_worked
  from table1
) x
pivot
(
  max(hours_worked)
  for p_date in ([2012-10-19], [2012-10-20], [2012-10-21])
) p
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b0dda/1)

If you have an unknown number of values, then you can use dynamic sql to `PIVOT` the data:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' 
                        + QUOTENAME(convert(char(10), p_date, 120)) 
                    from table1
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT dept, emp_id, emp_name,' + @cols + ' from 
             (
                select dept, emp_id, emp_name, p_date, hours_worked
                from table1
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(hours_worked)
                for p_date in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b0dda/4)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution.  Does this code work with SQL Server 2000 as well?

Comment: No the PIVOT function was not available until 2005. You have this tagged as 2008, do you need a 2000 solution?

Comment: Was busy with some other stuff. It was all that I required but also looking for SQL Server 2000. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I got this Msg 170, Level 15, State 1 Line 13: Incorrect syntax near 'XML'.

Comment: @MohdMohiuddin what version of SQL server are you running this in?

Comment: @MohdMohiuddin can you recreate this sql fiddle (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b0dda/4) with some of your sample data and the query you are using? Without seeing your query it is difficult to determine your error.

Comment: It's a view.  The view is similar to your table1.  I shall create sql fiddle later. Please don't mind.  I have multiple tasks to perform. I appreciate your patience.